# Issue with Discord PY, Async and websockets

Tags: python, websocket, async-await, discord

I am getting errors that GRBOT.on_message and GRBOT.on_open arent being awaited, and after many edits I cannot seem to trace where these need to be awaited at.

For context this code is in my main.py file with my Discord bot code below so that I can send commands in my discord to the websocket of the site I am sending and receiving data from. Any help is appreciated.

```
import websocket #pip install websocket-client
import json
import time
import os
from pprint import pprint
import re
import discord  #api
import keep_alive  #keeps our bot alive from the keep_alive.py file
import asyncio   #creating loop tasks etc 
import random
import requests
from discord.ext import tasks, commands
from discord.utils import get


class GRBOT:
    async def __int__(self):
        self.ws = None
        self.bot_name = 'GR BOT'
        self.channel_id = '###'
        self.rvrb_api_key = '###'
        self.song_history = []
        self.messages = []
        self.event_handlers = {
            'keepAwake': self.stay_awake,
            'updateChannelDjs': self.update_dj_queue,
            'updateChannelUsers': self.update_users,
            'playChannelTrack': self.now_playing,
            'updateChannelHistory': self.update_song_history,
            'updateChannelMeter': self.update_votes,
            'pushChannelMessage': self.new_message,
        }
        self.dj_queue = []
        self.users = {}
        #self.qt = QuickThemes()
        #self.strawpoll_id = None
        
    async def update_votes(self, data):
        self.votes = data['params']
        
    async def new_message(self, data):
        trigger_prefix = '+'
        message = data['params']['payload'].strip()
        print(f"{self.users[data['params']['userId']]['displayName']}: {message}")
        if message.startswith(trigger_prefix):
            command = message[1:].lower().split()[0]
            if command in commands:
                response = commands[command](self, data)
                if isinstance(response, str):
                   self.send_message(response)
            else:
                self.send_message("I am a black hole shitting into the void")
        self.messages.append(data['params'])
        if len(self.messages) > 100:
            self.messages.pop(0)

        
    async def update_users(self, data):
        """
        I think I'll want to mostly use this to correlate IDs to display names..
        converted to a dict.
        """
        self.users = {user['_id']: user for user in data['params']['users']}

    async def update_song_history(self, data):
        self.song_history.append(data['params'])
        if len(self.song_history) > 100:
            self.song_history.pop(0)

    async def update_dj_queue(self, data):
        self.dj_queue = data['params']['djs']
        #self.qt.handle_qt_dj_queue(self)

    async def now_playing(self, data):
        self.now_playing = data['params']
        #if self.strawpoll_id:
            #result = responses.poll_results(self)
            #self.send_message(result)
        #responses.artist_announcements(self)
        # self.qt.handle_now_playing(self)
        #self.qt.handle_song_change(self)
        songs_played =[f"{i['playedBy']['displayName']}---{i['track']['name']}---{i['track']['artists'][0]['name']}" for i in self.song_history]


    async def on_error(self, ws, data):
        pass
    

    async def stay_awake(self, data=None):
        stay_awake_data = {
            'jsonrpc': '2.0',
            'method': 'stayAwake',
            'params': {
                'date': str(int(time.time() * 1000))
            }
        }
        return stay_awake_data
    
    async def send_message(self, message):
        send_message = {
            'jsonrpc': '2.0',
            'method': 'pushMessage',
            'params': {
                'payload': message
            }
        }
        await self.ws.send(json.dumps(send_message))

    async def upvote(self):
        upvote = {
            'jsonrpc': '2.0',
            'method': 'vote',
            'params': {
                'dope': True
            }
        }
        await self.ws.send(json.dumps(upvote))

    async def on_open(self, data):
        print('Joining the room.')
        # join the specified channel when the connection is established
        join_data = {
            'method': 'join',
            'params': {
                'channelId': self.channel_id
            },
            'id': 1
        }
        bot_profile = {
            "method": "editUser",
            "params": {
                "image": "https://app.rvrb.one/static/6307b6c6f07c2a50d46e6f8b_image.gif",
                "bio": """  Hi, I'm Paul!""",
            }
        }
        await self.ws.send(json.dumps(join_data))
        await self.ws.send(json.dumps(bot_profile))
        



    async def on_message(self, ws, message):
        data = json.loads(message)
        if data.get('method') in self.event_handlers:
            response = self.event_handlers[data['method']](data)
            await self.ws.send(json.dumps(response))
        else:
            print(data.get('method'))

    async def run(self):
        # websocket.enableTrace(True)
        self.ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(f'wss://app.rvrb.one/ws-bot?apiKey=###',
                                on_error=self.on_error,
                                on_open=self.on_open,
                                on_message=self.on_message,)
        self.ws.run_forever(ping_interval=30)

async def main():
    bot = GRBOT()
    await bot.run()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

I have added await on nearly every function that I can think of in this code. I don't know if I am improperly using Async and await but I need it to be able to use my Discord side at the same time.

Comment: By `async def __int__`, do you mean `def __init__`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 when I used ```def __init__``` I got this error: TypeError: __init__() should return None, not 'coroutine'

Comment: Then you used `async def`, not `def`.

Comment: @mkrieger1 so I need all these functions to be async functions, does ```def __init__``` not need to have async if the rest of the functions are using asyncio?

Comment: So I changed to ```def __init__``` as you suggested and didnt error out. 

I am still getting errors on GRBOT.on_message, on_error and on_open not being awaited. I guess my problem is just missing where in this code I am missing the await